# Timeout on asynchronous BPEL process

Tags: asynchronous, timeout, bpel, apache-ode

I want to create a very simple asynchronous echo process. Therefore I created a BPEL process "EchoAsynch" [1] which returns the string it gets. This is the service which will be called by "eventHandler" [1]. In eventHandler I send the input via invoke to "EchoAsynch" and wait for receiving the answer with the "receive" activity. Problem is I never get an answer. The BPEL process times out after 120 seconds. Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Michael

P.S. I use Apache ODE 1.3.5 on a Tomcat Server (7.0.27) and test it in Eclipse with the BPEL Eclipse Designer.

[1] http://www.file-upload.net/download-4361941/processes.zip.html

Answer (score 0):

@Michael,
Once I invoked the eventHandler process, there was a selectionFailure thrown as follows.

[2012-05-16 22:46:22,922]  INFO - ASSIGN - Assignment Fault: {http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable}selectionFailure,lineNo=79,faultExplanation={http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable}selectionFailure: No results for expression: 'tns:result' against '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EchoAsynchProcessResponse xmlns="http://www.example.org/eventhandleras"><tns:result xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/eventhandler">tns:result</tns:result>
</EchoAsynchProcessResponse>'

So I fixed it and it worked. 
Note - I tried this in WSO2 BPS which is powered by Apache ODE. So I assume this should work in your environment too.
Please find my fixed samples at http://www.2shared.com/file/3ATXoeFd/processes.html

Comment: Hi Dennis,

thank you for your answer.

I changed deploy.xml to

`code`
[...]
<invoke partnerLink="client">
<service name="eventhandleras:EchoAsynchProcessCallback" port="EchoAsynchProcessCallbackPort">
</invoke>
[...]
`code`

but it still does not work. On http://localhost:8080/ode/services/listServices the service is display with following information:

Service Status : Active
Available Operations

    initiate

So it seems to be fine.